# Vagrant Box with Trellis/Bedrock

Tags: trellis

I recently set up a Trellis/Bedrock/Sage environment. I like it so far but have been running into the issue that if I step away from my computer, I can’t reconnect to my local production environment and have to start up my wordpress install from scratch. Is there a way to “save” a vagrant box so I can close my computer and not have to vagrant destroy, then vagrant up each time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could probably `Save State` directly in VirtualBox to accomplish what you want:

[image]

Also, I was able to find this comment to help answer your question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/578601/329575) which also may do the trick:

> In order to keep the same VM around and not loose its state, use the
>   vagrant suspend and vagrant resume commands. This will make your VM
>   survive a host machine reboot with its state intact.

- https://serverfault.com/users/210885/